# Parameters in Firebase Cloud Functions HTTPS

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

How can I set some parameters on my HTTPS functions in Firebase? 
I am building an app, and while building the app, I have managed to grow my mailing list. Now I want to send mails out, but I want to make sure that they can unsubscribe before I send anything out.

I am using Firebase for everything, and I have managed to make a function that sends mails out to every subscribed mail.

I am also able to "unsubscribe" a specific mail, but that is hardcoded, and not at all an optimal solution.

```
exports.testUnsub = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  var db = admin.database();
  var ref = db.ref("mailingList/-KhBOisltrOmv57Mrzus");
  ref.child("subscribed").set(false);
  console.log("-KhBOisltrOmv57Mrzus has unsubscribed from mailing list.");
});
```

In the mail I send there is an URL, which triggers this HTTPS function. I want to set a parameter on that URL so it becomes dynamic. Something like:

```
https://us-central1-<project-id>.cloudfunctions.net/testUnsub?listID=xxxxxxxxxxx
```

I am looking for anything that can get me on the right direction.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It's important to know that the req and res parameters to your https function are [Express.js](https://expressjs.com/) Request and Response objects.

The [Request](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req) object contains all the data about the request coming from the client, including the [query](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query) that the client sent in the URL.  It will take the form `req.query.name_of_the_parameter`.

Comment: But i get "Your client does not have permission to get URL" when i use `req.query.titl`

Comment: Doug is there any way with Cloud Functions to define and extract route parameters, similar to Express where you would do something like `app.get('/users/:userId/books/:bookId', function (req, res) { ... }`?

Comment: @PatNeedham you can check this [github link](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/authorized-https-endpoint/functions/index.js#L66) or [firebase doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#using_existing_express_apps) which utilizes the firebase functions as a normal express router. So that you can match with the endpoints in the ways you prefer.

Comment: For those that don't understand http request format, do `https://us-central1-<project-id>.cloudfunctions.net/testUnsub?exampleParam=x&anotherExampleParam=y`, and then use the `req.query.exampleParam` to access the contents.

Comment: @JoeMoore The question from Pat is about route parameters like `/users/123/` whereas your answer is about `/?user=123`. Different types of parameters.